# Quasi-ideals and Erdős conjecture on arithmetic progressions

Tags: nt.number-theory, ideals, noetherian, erdos

Starting to read a book about algebraic geometry as well as the Wikipedia article on Erdős conjecture on arithmetic progressions, I came to think of what follows.

Let $A$ be a set of positive integers, and define a $k$-quasi-ideal $J$ of $A$ as a set made of $k+1$ consecutive integers such that there is a couple $(a,c)\in A^{2}$ such that $a+cJ\subset A$, a quasi-ideal of $A$ being a $k$-quasi-ideal of $A$ for some positive integer $k$. I say $A$ is quasi-Noetherian if every increasing sequence of quasi-ideals of $A$ is stationary.

Does the following hold?

If $A$ is quasi-Noetherian, then $\sum_{n\in A}\frac{1}{n}<\infty$.

Comment: Being quasi-Noetherian is equivalent to $A$ not containing any infinite AP. There are subsets of $\mathbb N$ of density $1$ not containing infinite APs, so the claim is false.

Comment: Ok, it seems I forgot a condition. I edit.

Comment: When you say "consecutive integers" do you mean "consecutive elements of $A$"?

Comment: No, I mean "consecutive non negative integers".